# Things possible or not with a server component in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

In a Next.JS app, I have a server component:

```
<SentenceList showFlag={1} />
```

As one can see there is a parameter called showFlag which has the value 1 in the code above, but could have a different value.

I want the user of my app to be able to choose the value for *showFlag*.

Here is my question. To achieve what I want for the user do I need to make *SentenceList* a client component ? Which I would know how to do.

Or is there a skillful way to combine my server component with some client component that I would have to provide to allow the user to interact? Which I would not know how to do at this point. I have read that I can import a client component into a server component, but would need some hints on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating a parent component that contains your input component and the `<SentanceLis/>` component. To get input from the user, you will have to use state management which will require converting the parent component to the client component.

You can then fetch data on the client side using `useEffect()` based on user input and pass that data to the `<SentanceList/>` component to display it. Or you can pass the user input from the parent to `<SentanceList/>` as you showed in the question.

You cannot have a server component inside of the client component if they are to be rendered on the same page.

Comment: I am trying to follow your answer. My question is "can I keep SentenceList as a server component and do what I need to do?". If YES how ?

Comment: No! Because you are trying to fetch data according to the user input. 

To pass the input from the input element to the `SentanceList` component, you will need to put them in a common parent. (You know? "State lifting") In the next js, you have to use the client component to use useState() function. Here your parent component became a client component, and you can't put a server component inside a client component. That's why you have to convert the `SentaceList` component to the client component.

Comment: I see, this is what I wanted to know. I already knew that one could not import a server component inside a client component. But since I also read that it was possible to import a client component inside a server component. I wondered if this last option might hold a solution for what I wanted to do.